# what is the best way to have a Generic Comparer

Tags: c#, generics

I have a lot of comparer classes where the class being compared is simply checking the name property of the object and doing a string compare.  For example:

```
public class ExerciseSorter : IComparer<Exercise>
{
    public int Compare(Exercise x, Exercise y)
    {
        return String.Compare(x.Name, y.Name);
    }
}

public class CarSorter : IComparer<Car>
{
    public int Compare(Car x, Car y)
    {
        return String.Compare(x.Name, y.Name);
    }
}
```

what is the best way to have this code generic so i dont need to write redundant code over and over again.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I use one like this:

```
public class AnonymousComparer<T> : IComparer<T>
{
    private Comparison<T> comparison;

    public AnonymousComparer(Comparison<T> comparison)
    {
        if (comparison == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("comparison");
        this.comparison = comparison;
    }

    public int Compare(T x, T y)
    {
        return comparison(x, y);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var carComparer = new AnonymousComparer<Car>((x, y) => x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name));
```

If you're doing a straight property compare and the property type implements `IComparable` (for example an `int` or `string`), then, I also have this class which is a bit more terse to use:

```
public class PropertyComparer<T, TProp> : IComparer<T>
    where TProp : IComparable
{
    private Func<T, TProp> func;

    public PropertyComparer(Func<T, TProp> func)
    {
        if (func == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("func");
        this.func = func;
    }

    public int Compare(T x, T y)
    {
        TProp px = func(x);
        TProp py = func(y);
        return px.CompareTo(py);
    }
}
```

Usage of this one is:

```
var carComparer = new PropertyComparer<Car, string>(c => c.Name);
```

Comment: var carComparer = new AnonymousComparer<Car>((x,y)=>x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name))
   ?

Comment: @spender: Yes, that is the usage... did I make a mistake?  That looks the same as what I wrote.

Comment: 1st edition was var carComparer = new AnonymousComparer<Car>(x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name)) . Is correct now.

Comment: I miss null checks here ```x.Name.CompareTo()``` and ```return px.CompareTo(py);```

Comment: The `System.Collections.Generic.ComparisonComparer` does exactly this. I wonder why this class is `internal`.

Answer (score 8):

As of .NET 4.5, [creating a generic class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2557913/50776) to wrap a [`Comparison<T>` delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh.aspx) in an [`IComparer<T>` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx) implementation is not needed.

The framework offers the static [`Create` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh737198.aspx) on the [`Comparer<T>` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfttsh47) which takes a `Comparison<T>` delegate and returns a [`Comparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfttsh47.aspx) (which implements `IComparer<T>`).

Here's an example of how to use it:

```
// Sample comparison, any T will do.
Comparison<int> comparison = (x, y) => x.CompareTo(y)

// Get the IComparer.
IComparer<T> comparer = Comparer.Create(comparison);
```

Now, you can write lambda expressions which perform your comparisons and quickly wrap those in `IComparer<T>` implementations where an option to take a `Comparison<T>` delegate is not offered (such as the [`Sort` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx) on the [`List<T>` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

If all your classes have Name property, you could introduce `IHaveName` interface and create comparer like this:

```
public class NameComparer : IComparer<IHaveName>
{
    public int Compare(IHaveName x, IHaveName y)
    {
        return String.Compare(x.Name, y.Name);
    }
}
```